# Resetting a static variable back to false

Tags: c++, variables, c++11, static

Every minute new fruits are pushed into an assembly line and every fruit must be updated.  But only the bananas will issue a warning that a banana that is too ripe exists.
This warning must be given only once to represent all bananas.  Then the next minute, when new fruits pour in, the banana warning, if any, must be issued again.
How to make this work by modifying Banana::update() alone?  So no global variable to monitor this, no special AssemblyLine member function to check bananas only (because there are many types of fruits, and I don't want a special function for Banana to be called in main()).  Nothing outside of Banana::update() in fact, except perhaps a helper function in Banana or Fruit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

struct AssemblyLine {
    std::array<std::list<struct Fruit*>, 3> fruits;
    void createFruits();
    void updateAllFruits();
} myAssemblyLine;

struct Fruit {
    AssemblyLine& assemblyLine = myAssemblyLine;
    int ripeness = std::rand() % 10;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

struct Apple : Fruit { virtual void update() override {} };
struct Orange : Fruit { virtual void update() override {} };
struct Banana : Fruit { virtual void update() override; };

void AssemblyLine::createFruits() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        fruits[0].push_back (new Apple);
        fruits[1].push_back (new Orange);
        fruits[2].push_back (new Banana);
    }
}

void AssemblyLine::updateAllFruits() {
    for (const auto& list : fruits)
        for (Fruit* f : list)
            f->update();
}

void Banana::update() {
    // This banana must be updated, but now check which banana is the most ripe.
    static bool alreadyWarned = false;
    int maxRipeness = 0;
    for (auto x : assemblyLine.fruits[2])
        if (x->ripeness > maxRipeness) maxRipeness = x->ripeness;
    if (!alreadyWarned && maxRipeness > 7) {
        std::cout << "Warning!  There is a banana that is too ripe!\n";
        alreadyWarned = true;  // I want this warning to be stated at most once per minute.
    }
    // How to know when to reset alreadyWarned back to false?
}

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    for (int i = 0;  i < 5;  i++) {  // Each loop is a new minute, and I want the banana warning (if any) each minute.
        myAssemblyLine.createFruits();
        myAssemblyLine.updateAllFruits();
    }
    // Problem:  The banana warning is only issued in the first loop.
}
```

Perhaps there is a better way write Banana::update() than to use the static variable alreadyWarned?

Comment: I would personally be asking myself conceptually: does it make sense for the alreadyWarned flag to belong to Bananas? Is it a property of Bananas, or is it a property of the AssemblyLine?

Comment: Perhaps there are a few types of fruits (of the many kinds of fruits) that shall issue such a warning.

Comment: In my opinion it makes more sense for the AssemblyLine to have a Warnings collection with the time (or updatePass number) of the warning, the type of fruit the warning pertains to (and possibly other information such as the nature of the warning).

Comment: Isn't this a question for [codereview.se]?

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit.  I'm not asking about what style will best handle this.  I'm asking how to handle this without changing main().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the function-scope `static bool alreadyWarned` to the `class Banana` scope.  That is, make it a static member variable.  This isn't technically a global, but it is as useful as one, because it can be updated from outside the `update()` function.

Comment: And then put `Banana::alreadyWarned = false;` at the end of the loop in main()?  That works, but I stated that I wanted to make no changes in main().  Is there a way to avoid that, i.e. make the change in Banana::update() itself only?

Comment: @prestokeys: well you could add a parameter like `update(bool isFirstIteration)` and pass that as `true` in the first pass of each loop in `updateAllFruits()`.  Then whenever it's true, set `alreadyWarned = false` at the top of `update()`.

Comment: @ John.  Ok.  `static void AssemblyLine::endLoop() {Banana::alreadyWarned = false;}`, and then call `AssemblyLine::endLoop();` at the end of the loop in main() seems fine when I think about it.  It doesn't change the client code too much, and that extra line could be useful for other similar things too.  I'll accept your answer.  Thanks.  However, Matt thinks that alreadyWarned should not be in Banana at all, but part of something bigger in AssemblyLine.

Comment: I guess if there are multiple AssemblyLines running at the same time, then `Banana::alreadyWarned = false;` would create incorrect output from the other assembly lines, huh?  In which case, Matt's suggestion is the way to go?